# How to deal with two students who potentially colluded when one is unavailable?

Tags: plagiarism, cheating

We have two students in my department who handed in identical essays. As per our policy we scheduled independent meetings with both students to determine what happened. Going into these meetings our primary objective is to figure out which of the following 5 possibilities occurred:

1. The students worked jointly and wrote one essay
2. One student wrote the essay and knowingly allowed the other student to copy the essay
3. One student wrote the essay and the other student copied their essay without the first student's knowledge
4. The students worked independently and managed to write word for word identical essays (this seems unlikely)
5. The students independently copied the same source

One student is on medical leave and was therefore unable to attend the meeting. The student who attended the meeting showed us drafts of previous essays which have convinced us that neither (4) nor (5) occurred. Further, when we exclude the other student's essay, TurnItIn doesn't find anything of concern. We also are confident that the student who attended the meeting did not copy the essay from the other student. This leaves us with possibilities (1), (2), and (3).

Our policy states that both students would be punished for academic misconducted if either (1) or (2) occurred and only the other student would be punished if (3) occurred. It seems without talking to the other student we cannot really come to a fair conclusion. Without a decision the student who attended the meeting will have neither passed or failed the class and therefore is not eligible to retake the class nor take any class which has the class in question as a prerequisite. It is unlikely the student on medical leave will be back in time to make a timely decision. How should we proceed?

Comment: My gut reaction is "innocent until proven guilty." If you can't determine what the truth is, best to assume innocence.

Comment: @JimConant but you can sit in jail a long time waiting for your innocence to be proven.

Comment: I'm assuming that the student you spoke with claimed that he didn't knowingly assist the other student.  If that's the case, then you pretty much have to let this student off the hook since you can't prove collusion.

Comment: Probably not an optimal decision, but you can assign an IN grade until the decision is made, and then maybe waive the prerequisite for any class which requires this class as a prerequisite.  Usually waiving the prerequisite is a department decision... The student involved know exactly if he cheated or not, so he should be able to plan accordingly...

Comment: @BrianBorchers The exact phrasing is "you cannot prove collision YET". Usually in these cases a decision is postponned... You cannot know what evidence the other student can bring....

Comment: In a criminal case if a prosecuter can't bring witnesses to court in a timely fashion, then their testimony simply won't be admitted and the case will proceed.  If the second student is really unavailable for a long period of time then it is unfair to withhold judgement on the first student's case.

Comment: @StrongBad: My point is not to draw a connection to criminal justice, but to the underlying philosophy that it's better to let a guilty party go free than to wrongly punish an innocent person.

Comment: Also, if you find solid evidence of guilt later on, is there any way to retroactively assign a penalty of some kind? For example if a student of mine, whom I assigned an A, was later shown to have cheated, I could retroactively change their grade according to our university's policy.

Comment: As a previous student, I had this happen to me, but I didn't collude. A classmate wanted to look at my project so I naively sent him my Word doc. Him and his girlfriend turned in the exact same copy albeit mine was in full color and theirs was in black/white. We both got zeroes until someone fessed up. Former classmate and girlfriend fessed up. They got zeroes, I got an 87. I ended up with a 3.5 GPA at graduation, he had a 2.5 GPA. This was 12 years ago.

Comment: au­di­a­tur et al­te­ra pars

Comment: Possibly simple-minded question: Why does this case need to be settled *now*?  Assuming that the other student will be back by finals, why don't you just tell the student who is available "we need to talk with the other student.  Keep going to class, etc., and we'll determine who cheated at the end of semester."?  This has the added advantage that, if he did collude, he may just decide to stop putting effort into the class entirely (building a case against him).

Comment: Bring a basket of fruits to visit the sick student and incidentally question him during the visit.

Comment: Possibilities (1), (2) and (3) all involve one or both of the students being *incredibly* stupid.

Comment: If you just dont know who is guilty then if there is a BIG grade difference in the final Exam then all will be revealed .If you had a proper policy that you must get 50% in the final to pass the course irrespective of homework then the guilty one will FAIL.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Not letting this student move forward at this point would be punishment. If there is a chance that you will find the student innocent of any wrongdoing, it seems like the injustice of punishing them for something they did not do is  worse than letting them get away with something they did.

Make it clear to the student that they will pass the class given the lack of evidence against them but that you will continue to evaluate the situation. Make sure they know that if you conclude later that they have colluded, you will update their grade to a failing one and force them to retake the class.

The only real negative consequence of this is that the student might be able to take classes that require this class as a prerequisite before they are forced to go back and take the original class again. That's not ideal, but it doesn't really seem so bad.

Comment: It's not really a negative that the student might have to go back after taking classes that required the given one as a prerequisite - the offshoot there is that the student gets to go ahead if they are innocent. If they're lying, then it would only be reasonable for them to admit guilt and take the class again - since otherwise, they'd just waste time in some other class before they're forced back. So the student gets a chance to be make a choice, and if they choose to take a class they know they haven't satisfied the prerequisites for, well, that'll be their problem when they're discovered.

Comment: The reason course 1 is a prerequisite for course 2 is that a student is unlikely to understand course 2 without first understanding course 1. If the student proves they understand course 2 by passing that course, who cares if they are subsequently failed on course 1? It's unusual administratively but it in no way invalidates their pass on course 2.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: That may be the *idea behind* the prerequisite, but, depending on the respective university's rules, fulfilling the prerequisite can easily be enforced. If passing of course 2 is defined as "having passed course 1 + achieving X points in the exam on course 2", a later discovery of a failing in course 1 would obviously invalidate the passing of course 2. What would be unusual administratively is that the student *might* be given a chance to pass course 1 *after* passing the exam of course 2, thus fulfilling the requirements of passing course 2 in the opposite to normal order.

Answer (score 15):

If you are convinced that the student who attended the meeting wrote the essay in question, then you must conclude that either the other student stole a copy or the two students collaborated.  I think that almost requires grades of "Incomplete" for both students until the matter can be resolved.

Edited to add: I like Nick S's comment about waiving the prerequisites for the student who attended the meeting.  His is a comment to the original question, and is worth reading.

Answer (score 13):

I know this can only apply to some of the situations, but if the student is unable to attend, yet still able to communicate I would say:

**Have you considered scheduling a call?**

You can just do the talk by phone, or Skype and documents can be scanned and mailed. 
Perhaps this is not as good as a face to face meeting, but I would say there is a good chance that you can clear things up this way.

Comment: If I might add, you could also ask of the sick student to come for a meeting or... provide a note from his medical doctor saying he is not fit to do so. Then see what happens.

Answer (score 10):

In my university we have a general rule: **If you collude, you both fail that assignment. If you took another student's assignment and copied it (stole from a classmate) then you not only fail the assignment but you fail the subject and must retake it**. Note: It is possible to fail and assignment and still pass the subject by resubmitting the failing work (as I believe most UK universities do and I believe you are in the UK).

I do not believe there is a perfect solution but by having a rule such as this, you can mostly avoid having one student say "It is my original work" when really it was joint work **because they would not want to save their friend at the cost of retaking the module (when they could both pass, albeit with a lower grade).**

If you have the same rule and the student in front of you is very clear about that and the student in front of you says "Yes, this is mine, all mine, he must have stolen from me" then I would let that student pass (without any contradicting evidence from the other student).

The challenge with such a rule in this case is that they might have colluded but the other student might simply take the fall, if only because he has nothing to lose because he's out on medical leave and cannot complete the module this term anyway. So, he might as well fall on his sword.

In your case (where one student is unavailable) I would have the student present sign some simple declaration ("It's my original work and the other student must have stolen it from me and I agree if the above is found to be untrue then my grade will be changed after-the-fact.")

I **would not** worry about the student taking subjects which need this subject as a pre-req. If he doesn't understand, that will be shown clearly later and will sort itself out.

Again, it's not a perfect rule but it mostly prevents colluding students from getting away with it by imposing double punishment on one.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer, I would like to bring up a question. Are the drafts conclusive evidence that (4) and (5) can be excluded? As far as (4) is unlikely, I find (5) highly likely. My question is extended to ask what was the time frame between finding the plagiarism, informing the students of the plagiarism, and the submission of the drafts by the student who isn't on sick leave?

As most "drafts" are neither handwritten or typed on a typewriter, the ease and quickness that a draft can be made does not remove doubt that the work isn't of the student.

If (1) and (2) are options, and this brings into suspect their collusion, then don't think that they still wouldn't be colluding in the fallout.

Answer (score -1):

I have another idea. Are the students both of the same sex? I just found something interesting that may help.

This site analyzes text for traits statistically associated with the sex of the writer.

http://www.hackerfactor.com/GenderGuesser.php

It seems to be fairly accurate. It correctly identified George Eliot as female (it was not fooled by her male pseudonym, LOL), and me as male. I also used it to analyze a text translated by male and female translators of a male writer (the same passage of about 600 words). The male translator's text came out 8% more 'masculine'.

If the test text comes out 'female' and one or both of the students is male, you have reason to suspect one or both has copied it. But of course, this is only one tool and must be viewed as such. It is just a piece of evidence to add to whatever other evidence you may have. To 'calibrate' the system, you could run all the students' papers through the process to see if it correctly identifies the male and female students in the class.

Of course, if both students are male or female, and the analysis does not show any discrepancy, it is of no help in determining which of the five possibilities occurred.

Comment: You can't punish or not punish a student based on the result of this test. The fact that it is often right is not enough to justify **failing a student**. See my answer for details for why I think that "innocent until proven guilty" is the correct approach.

Answer (score -2):

It's hard to believe that *both* students would have agreed to turn in identical papers. Most students would know that turning in a paper identical to some other student's would certainly be noticed. So, it is more likely that only *one* of them is the culprit. In this case, this student is most likely stupid as well as dishonest. The question is how do we tell who is lying? I believe King Solomon had a similar problem, when two woman claimed to be the mother of a single child. You might want to offer to give *half* credit to each. The one who cheated would likely object less.

Comment: Despite repeatedly telling them group work is not allowed, we often get identical papers from students. As for offering half credit and then trying to gauge objections, especially when one student is unavailable, seems like an awful idea.

Comment: Apparently there is a communication problem if that is happening 'often'. Are these students Oriental? Culturally, some east Asian societies encourage group endeavor, the Japanese in particular.

Comment: I have never heard of such a thing regarding Asian people, and I'm Asian.